# @foreach in @foreach have double data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two array `$softwarelist` and `$virt_software_select` when i use `@foreach` in blade template like below code i got checked but `$softwarelist` is double in label.

```
$softwarelist =["Adobe Photoshop","Adobe Illustrator","Corel Draw","My SQL","Oracle"];
$virt_software_select=["Adobe Photoshop","My SQL"];

@foreach($softwarelist as $slst)
    @foreach($virt_software_select as $sw_usr)
        @if($slst->software==$sw_usr->virtualize_software)
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked name="virt_software[]" value="{{$slst->software}}"/> 
                  {{$slst->software}}
            </label>
        @else
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="virt_software[]" value="{{$slst->software}}"/> 
                  {{$slst->software}}
            </label> 
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

i got these
[image]

How can i get checked the same data in two array but not double data with `$softwarelist` in laravel?

Comment: Hey can you explain me more about your question, like what are you planing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **in_array()** php function then it will work and use only one foreach

```
$softwarelist =["Adobe Photoshop","Adobe Illustrator","Corel Draw","My SQL","Oracle"];
$virt_software_select=["Adobe Photoshop","My SQL"];

@foreach($softwarelist as $slst)
    @if(in_array($slst,$virt_software_select))
        <?php $checked ="checked"; ?>
    @else
        <?php $checked =""; ?>
    @endif
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" {{$checked}} name="virt_software[]" value="{{$slst->software}}"/> 
              {{$slst->software}}
        </label>
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i got an error in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: make sure you have entered right array in in_array() function

Comment: make sure this variable is in array form $virt_software_select

Answer (score 0):

You have to use in_array() function instead of using nested foreach

```
$softwarelist =["Adobe Photoshop","Adobe Illustrator","Corel Draw","My SQL","Oracle"];
$virt_software_select=["Adobe Photoshop","My SQL"];

@foreach($softwarelist as $slst)
    <label>
    @if(in_array($slst,$virt_software_select))
         <input type="checkbox" checked name="virt_software[]" value="{{$slst->software}}"/>{{$slst->software}}
    @else
         <input type="checkbox" name="virt_software[]" value="{{$slst->software}}"/>{{$slst->software}}
    @endif
    </label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Update Code Removed <pre> tag